# Local imports with subfolders in Python

Tags: python, python-import

Suppose I have an import that is using a package within the project (Python 3.10):

```
import foo.bar
```

Where the import statement is in main.py with a folder structure of:

```
main.py
foo
  var.py
```

Then I "pip install foo" and the program breaks: the global foo shadows the local foo. Adding __init__.py to foo reverses the shadow problem and I can't use the global foo in my program. **Edit:** It also seems to prevent using any external libraries that import foo.

So let's make it a relative import instead:

```
from . import foo.bar
```

But it doesn't like the . in foo.bar and complains with "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Is there a way around this problem? "from .foo import bar", "from . import foo", and other variants I tried don't work.

Edit: **SSCCE** Tested on windows, should also work on linux. It **installs** an obscure library (python-dogecoin), runs python (it checks for a function in the library, but doesn't actually run it), and then **uninstalls** it.

testfolder/dogecoinrpc/bar.py:

```
import random
def will_it_crash(date=None):
    return random.random()>0.8
```

In terminal:

```
cd path/to/testfolder
```

In terminal this can be cut and pasted (Note: this temporary will install *python-dogecoin*):

```
echo "We begin one level above of the dogecoinrpc folder"
pip uninstall python-dogecoin
y

python
import dogecoinrpc.bar as bar # Should work.
bar.will_it_crash() # Should work.
quit()

pip install python-dogecoin
python
import dogecoinrpc.bar as bar #ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dogecoinrpc.bar'
bar.will_it_crash() # NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
import dogecoinrpc # Should work.
client_fn = dogecoinrpc.connect_to_local # Should work
quit()

python
with open('./dogecoinrpc/__init__.py', 'w') as _:
    pass

quit()

python
import dogecoinrpc.bar as bar
bar.will_it_crash() # Should work.
import dogecoinrpc # Appears to work, but:
client_fn = dogecoinrpc.connect_to_local # AttributeError: module 'dogecoinrpc' has no attribute 'connect_to_local'
quit()

echo "Now lets clean up."
python
import os
os.remove("./dogecoinrpc/__init__.py")
quit()

pip uninstall python-dogecoin
y
echo "Cleaned up"
```

Comment: How exactly does `from .foo import bar` fail?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Comment: What is a local import? Do you have a reference, or is it something you made up?

Comment: Can you provide your folder structure?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: It's actually a "relative" import, fixed the term.

Comment: Makes sense. That only works in a package. Run your module with -m to enable relative imports

Comment: Or keep your driver scripts outside the library. That's how I prefer to do it

Comment: #1 don't cause naming conflicts. If you know foo exists, call your top level package something else. #2 I'm not sure I believe that installing foo breaks your program. Default install locations come after the path to your file in python's module search order

Comment: Can you please show a mcve that imports  var correctly when foo is not installed and breaks when it is? Include the contents of all three python files, and all shell commands you run, along with exceptions

Comment: I'd like to try to replicate in a fresh venv with something like foo=numpy

Comment: @MadPhysicist tested it on numpy and yes it breaks. SO doesn't like me attaching code so I can't really add an SSCCE.

Comment: You can create 3 files of < 10 lines to demonstrate the problem and show their content here. An MCVE is the smallest example that demonstrates the issue, not a code dump

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I added the MCVE that shows the problems, although it installs an obscure module temporarily rather than using venv. Key error messages are in the comments of the pasted example.